How can I schedule iOS live activity to start at specific time?
I need to start my non-changing live activity at specific time e.g. after 5 mins or 1 hour. There are two way I can start at later date:

Using Local notification, but I will need the user to interact with
it for it to actually call a method which starts the activity. May be user doesn't see that local notification and I will not get chance to start activity by calling a method.
Using push notifications, we can start live activity. But my live activity doesn't update once I start it. Here is why:

I am using one of the system UI components ProgressView that support auto-updating a live activity. So once I start live activity, the progress bas updated automatically every second, and that's why I don't need a push notifications to update my activity.
struct GymWidgetAttributes: ActivityAttributes {
    
    var startDate: Date
    var endDate: Date

    // 'ContentState' represents the dynamic content of the Live Activity.
    public struct ContentState: Codable, Hashable {
        // Dynamic stateful properties about activity
        var gymTimer: ClosedRange<Date>
    }
}

Here is how activity is updated:
ProgressView(
    timerInterval: context.state.gymTimer,
    countsDown: false
)
.tint(.gray)

The reason why I do not want to use push notifications is my activity doesn't updates once it is started. Is there some other way, or I will have to use push notifications?

Push notifications are the only way to guarantee that an activity starts at a specific time.

Okay, I will implement it using push notifications
